# How to loop through binary blocks using python and stop at file end?

Tags: python, binaryfiles, eof, sequential

I have a binary file that needs to be read sequentially because it is structured in variable-size blocks that self-describe themselves at start.

I thus want to loop through a set of:
+ get next block structure and limits
+ parse it
+ move on to the next block.

At some point I need to now that the file has reached an end.

How can I do this since python doesn't have an EOF check to put in a while loop?

Answers to similar questions online simply stated that you can stop your parsing when the file.read() gives you back no bytes or less bytes than you ask for.

Fine, but after parsing one block I need to read next byte to do that, which is annoying because it could be a byte that is part of the next structure definition.

Below the couple of while loops I devised to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

1) Taking advantage of the file.read(num_of_bytes) in python, that can tell you there are no more bytes to read one solution could be

```
while (dat.read(1)):
    dat.seek(-1,1)
    [your business here]
```

The back-seek lets you continue from where you left in the previous block.

2) If you know your file doesn't change while reading it, you can take advantage of its length and simply use

```
flength = os.stat(your_file).st_size # your file size in bytes
while (dat.tell() < flength):
        [your business here]
```

Takes advantage of the .tell() method that gives you the byte you're on in the file.